# How to Implement Search with Pagination using Ajax codigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pagination

**Controller**

```
 function view_product() 
    {     
        $config = [
            'base_url'          =>  base_url('admin/view_product'),
            'per_page'          =>  10,
            'total_rows'        =>  $this->AdminModel->num_rows(NULL),
            'full_tag_open'     =>  "<ul class='pagination'>",
            'full_tag_close'    =>  "</ul>",
            'first_tag_open'    =>  '<li>',
            'first_tag_close'   =>  '</li>',
            'last_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'last_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'next_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'next_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'prev_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'prev_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'num_tag_open'      =>  '<li>',
            'num_tag_close'     =>  '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open'      =>  "<li class='active'><a>",
            'cur_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',
        ];

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['page'] =($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['product'] =$this->AdminModel->view_product(NULL,$config['per_page'],$data['page']);  
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('admin/view_product',$data);

    }

 public function ajaxsearch()
     {
          $query = $this->input->post('query');
          print_r($this->AdminModel->num_rows($query));         

          $config = [
            'base_url'          =>  base_url('admin/ajaxsearch'),
            'per_page'          =>  10,
            'total_rows'        =>  $this->AdminModel->num_rows($query),
            'full_tag_open'     =>  "<ul class='pagination'>",
            'full_tag_close'    =>  "</ul>",
            'first_tag_open'    =>  '<li>',
            'first_tag_close'   =>  '</li>',
            'last_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'last_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'next_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'next_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'prev_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
            'prev_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
            'num_tag_open'      =>  '<li>',
            'num_tag_close'     =>  '</li>',
            'cur_tag_open'      =>  "<li class='active'><a>",
            'cur_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',

        ];

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['page'] =($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['product'] =$this->AdminModel->view_product($query,$config['per_page'],$data['page']);
        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $this->load->view('admin/product_search_result',$data,false);

     }
```

**Model**

```
public function num_rows($searchKeyword=NULL)
    {
        if ($searchKeyword == "NULL") $searchKeyword = "";

        $query = $this->db
                      ->select('*')
                      ->from('product')
                      ->like('p_name',$searchKeyword)
                      ->get();                  

        return $query->num_rows();

    }

 function view_product($searchKeyword=NULL,$limit,$offset)
    {
            if ($searchKeyword == "NULL") $searchKeyword = "";

            $query = $this->db->select("*")
                              ->from('product')
                              ->limit($limit, $offset )
                              ->join('product_category', 'product.p_cid = product_category.p_cid')
                              ->join('company','product.c_id = company.c_id')
                              ->order_by('p_id')
                              ->like('p_name',$searchKeyword)
                              ->get();
            return $query->result();
    }
```

**View**

```
function load_data(query)
      {
            $.ajax({
                      url:"<?php echo base_url();?>admin/view_product",
                      method:"POST",
                      data:{query:query},
                      success:function(data)
                      { 
                          $('#showData').html(data);
                          $('#product_list').html(data);
                      }
                    });
      }

  $('#product_name').keyup(function()
      {
          var search = $(this).val();
          if(search != '')
          {
             load_data(search);
          }
        /*  else
          {
             load_data();
          }*/
      });
```

I am new to C.I, I am creating a Search Filter, The filter is working properly until i moved to the next Pagination link. When i am on First link the data is showing according to the filter/search keyword, but as i move to the next link everything goes off (All the data shows on page) how to solve this problem ?

Comment: You can create a extra function like 'view_product' say ' view_product_by_key' AdminModel with an extra parameter eg view_product_by(para1,para2,keyword) .

Comment: still not working @kashif

Comment: Please check the below code (use your own variable)

Comment: have you check the variable name .. i have used name=  'searchKeyword' and you have use id #product_name . please do considered it

Comment: yes i check it. it is fine @kashif

Comment: @mark . can you explain what is the issue you are facing .. ERROR or Response

Comment: here you can see i am using ajax for search request and return response is load the product page so i did not get propery response@kashif

Comment: Please check the value  returned by this $results with die keyword . or you can console the response

Comment: ok.i get the properly result but my question  is my response result is bind with  #showData div in above manner ?? @kashif

Comment: Please clear me one thing . the $result  is getting the expected data  OR the problem is in showing on view ??? OR both

Comment: now i have issue on showing the results on view @kashif

Comment: your code look fine . i am more interested in the  'console.log(data);' . please use this in your ajax success function  , and show me the response (screenshot) , so that i can analysis the error . if there is any .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to have one function for both searching & pagination in CONTROLLER and have two separate function in MODEL

```
function view_product() 
{     
    $config = [
        'base_url'          =>  base_url('admin/view_product'),
        'per_page'          =>  10,
        'total_rows'        =>  $this->AdminModel->num_rows(NULL),
        'full_tag_open'     =>  "<ul class='pagination'>",
        'full_tag_close'    =>  "</ul>",
        'first_tag_open'    =>  '<li>',
        'first_tag_close'   =>  '</li>',
        'last_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
        'last_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
        'next_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
        'next_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
        'prev_tag_open'     =>  '<li>',
        'prev_tag_close'    =>  '</li>',
        'num_tag_open'      =>  '<li>',
        'num_tag_close'     =>  '</li>',
        'cur_tag_open'      =>  "<li class='active'><a>",
        'cur_tag_close'     =>  '</a></li>',
    ];

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $data['page'] =($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    if(@$this->input->post('searchKeyword')==null)
    {
    $results=$this->AdminModel->view_product($config["per_page"],$page);    
    }
    else
    {
    $searchKeyword=$this->input->post('searchKeyword'); 
    $results=$this->AdminModel->view_product_withKey($config["per_page"],$page,$searchKeyword);
    }
    $data['product']=$results;
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('admin/view_product',$data);

}
```

MODEL

```
public function view_product($limit,$start)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->where('status',TRUE);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

public function view_product_withKey($limit,$start,$searchKeyword)
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $this->db->like('field1', $searchKeyword);
    $this->db->or_like('fiel2', $searchKeyword);
    $this->db->or_like('field3', $searchKeyword);
    $this->db->or_like('field4', $searchKeyword);
    $this->db->where('status',TRUE);
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

Please test the code . AND do considered the variable name . please use your variable respectively.

Comment: thanks one more help how to manage view side i am using ajax  i  show you my view file. @kashif

Comment: please vote my answer if you find helpful . please share the view file @make